# Google Maps API styling error

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map) about how to style a google map, but the styling is not working, showing just a gray square on the screen (the div I created).
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #map_canvas {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                background-color: #CCC;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
                var styles = [
                  {
                    featureType: 'road',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [
                      { color: '#000000' },
                      { weight: 1.6 }
                    ]
                  }, {
                    featureType: 'road',
                    elementType: 'labels',
                    stylers: [
                      { saturation: -100 },
                      { invert_lightness: true }
                    ]
                  }, {
                    featureType: 'landscape',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [
                      { hue: '#ffff00' },
                      { gamma: 1.4 },
                      { saturation: 82 },
                      { lightness: 96 }
                    ]
                  }, {
                    featureType: 'poi.school',
                    elementType: 'geometry',
                    stylers: [
                      { hue: '#fff700' },
                      { lightness: -15 },
                      { saturation: 99 }
                    ]
                  }
                ];
                var styledMap = new google.maps.styleMapType(styles,{name: "styled Map"});
                var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
                var map_options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
                    }
                }
               var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
               map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
               map.setMapTypeId('map_style');   
             }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the JavaScript debugger. Have you used one before? Every browser has developer tools available these days. My favorite is the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

If you load your code with the DevTools open, you'll see it stop on the line with the error:

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.styleMapType(styles,{name: "styled Map"});
```

Roll the mouse over the various names on that line. You'll see that `google` is defined, and `google.maps` is defined, but `google.maps.styleMapType` is `undefined`.

Compare that line with the tutorial or the documentation and you'll see that what you need is `StyledMapType`, not `styleMapType`.

Fix that and your map will work.

But please, don't just take this fix and run with it. Spend some time with the Developer Tools and get familiar with them. This will save you many hours of time in your future debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't know these tools.

Comment: My pleasure. Once you start working with those developer tools, you'll love them. It makes it so much easier to see what is going on in your code. So definitely explore all of the things they offer.